# Simple many to many issue

Tags: sql-server, ssas

So here is the context, I have:

- 2 fact tables (that have a one to many relationship in a relationnal model):

  ```
  - Med_Sejour_Episode

  - Med_Consultation
  ```
- 3 Dimensions:

  ```
  - Ref_Date : A date dimension related to Med_Sejour_Episode and Med_Consultation (Both facts have their own date field)

  - Med_AdmissionType : A dimension related to Med_Sejour_Episode

  - Med_DomaineConsultation : A dimension related to Med_Consultation
  ```
- 1 Bridge:

  ```
  - Med_BridgeConsultation : That bridges Med_Sejour_Episode and Med_Consultation
  ```

So when I settup the cube without the date dimension everything is fine, result output is correct using either Med_Admissiontype or Med_domaineConsultation dimension for both facts measures

Tables relationship:
[image: Tables relationship]

Dimension Usage:
[image: Dimension Usage]

Excel output:
[image: Excel output]

However when I settup the cube with the date dimension on both facts table my result output is not balancing anymore when using Med_domaineConsultation Dimension with Med_Sejour_Episode fact table measure.

Result output is still correct if I use date dimension with both fact or if I use dimension and fact that are directly related.

Dimension Usage:
[image: Dimension Usage]

Excel output:
[image: Excel output]

Do you know why and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know if I can put a link to another forum here but I asked the same question there and the answer could help other people. (let me know and I will remove the link)

[Link to ssas forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ff8bde95-d806-42bd-8682-746718036521/ssas-simple-many-to-many-issue?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

Also I will mark this thread as answered as soon as I close the thread on SSAS forum.

Comment: So my issue has been resolved and you can find the answer to the link I posted before (let me know if you want me to post the answer here direclty)